# Is deleting tasks and pools necessary in Azure batch jobs?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-batch

The [Azure Batch .net tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/batch-dotnet-get-started/) shows deleting tasks, then jobs, then pools. At the same time, I found this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/azure-batch-task-monitoring-and-cost-saving1) about cleanup, instead of deleting jobs and pools, it just deletes VMs which are no longer used. Is this a good strategy? I see that it can help keep track of tasks and general organization, but what are the implications of keeping tasks, jobs and pools after deleting the completed tasks’ vms?

**Update 2018-05-15**

Maximum number of tasks in a given job is 7770.

I have followed the answer below and finally ended up with a job that had accumulated 7770 tasks. After this magical number, the batch service was no longer able to add new tasks to the job, throwing the following exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Common.BatchException: InternalError: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
RequestId:e6ab60e0-5c3b-4116-9ffb-ba2032154318
Time:2018-05-15T11:17:17.2186951Z
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.CloudPoolOperations.<GetAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.BatchRequest`2.<ExecuteRequestWithCancellationAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.BatchRequest`2.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.ProtocolLayer.<ProcessAndExecuteBatchRequest>d__11b`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.PoolOperations.<GetPoolAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.PoolOperations.GetPool(String poolId, DetailLevel detailLevel, IEnumerable`1 additionalBehaviors)
   at Pepe.Helpers.Batch.CreatePool()
   at Pepe.Helpers.LogEntryMaintainer.LaunchJob(LogFile log, PepeEntities db)
```

I suggest a regular cleanup of historical data. If you need to retain this information somewhere, I suggest moving somewhere, like table storage.

Comment: The batch-file tag is for Windows .bat files.  Not sure what this has to do with that.

Comment: @Squashman it keeps changing “batch” to “batch-file”. Strange thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to delete tasks or their jobs at all and there's no real downside of leaving them in the system. You *do* however need to terminate jobs on completion as there is a quota on the number of active jobs within a Batch account.

With respect to pools and VMs, that's really up to you as to how you want to manage resources (particularly given these cost you money). Common approaches include;

- Explicitly create a pool to run one or more jobs. Delete the pool once finished. The pool can also be explicitly resized if you want to increase/decrease the number of VMs.
- Use the Autopool feature to specify a pool to be created automatically with job submission. The pool will be automatically deleted when the job is terminated.
- Explicitly create a pool and define an autoscale formula that can scale the pool up and down as jobs are submitted and complete. This is a very powerful feature for maximizing resource utilization and minimizing cost.

Hope that helps.